# Creating an ActionScript 3 RSS looping feed

Tags: actionscript-3, rss

I have the following AS3 code so far. What I need to do is have this code continually loop the feed it is consuming. Any solutions?

```
    import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;


//Read RSS feeds
var RSS_xmlData: XML = new XML();
var xmlLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.oshawa.ca/news_rss.asp"));

function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
    dtext.text="Loading...";
    RSS_xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
}

function pullFeed(rss: XML):void {      
    var str: String="";
    str = rss.channel.item.title;
    str = str.replace(/\s*\n/g," | ");
    str = str.replace(/&#39;/g,"\"");
    //// shows specific entry  
    var items: Array = new Array();
    items = str.split("|");

    var tf: TextField = dtext;
    var i:Number=0;
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(4000,items.length);
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
    function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{
        tf.text = items[i].toString();
        scaleTextToFitInTextField(tf);
        i++;
    }
    myTimer.start();
}

function scaleTextToFitInTextField(txt: TextField):void {
    var f: TextFormat = txt.getTextFormat();
    f.size = (txt.width > txt.height) ? txt.width : txt.height;
    txt.setTextFormat(f);

    while (txt.textWidth > txt.width - 4 || txt.textHeight > txt.height - 6) {
        f.size = int(f.size) - 1;
        txt.setTextFormat(f);
    }
}


function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(e.toString());
    dtext.text="Finding Feed...";
}
```

I have tried a while loop, a for loop and a timer reset and restart but none appear to enable me to continually loop the feed.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'continually loop the feed'? Do you want to load and parse it continually on some interval?

Comment: Currently as you can see it parse the feed and displays the Title every 4 seconds until the all the feeds titles have been displayed.

I need it to start that all over again continually.

Comment: Where are you calling pullFeed from?

Comment: Oops! Sorry I must have deleted in deleting the commented out code. It goes into the LoadXML function as pullFeed(RSS_xmlData)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset your counter when you've finished iterating over your `array`:

```
function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{
    tf.text = items[i].toString();
    scaleTextToFitInTextField(tf);
    // Reset counter to 0 when we've been all the way through the array
    i = i < items.length - 1 ? i + 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Duh..to long in front of the monitor again. Thank you for that! I of course had to also change

'var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(4000,items.length);'
to
' var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(4000,1000);'
to get it to continue

Comment: Did you notice that the feed title comes in with the xml markup?!? Do you know how to fix that and should I open a new question for that?